# Entities Mapping

Tags: entity, symfony

i get this error in the Entities Mapping
**The association EventBundle\Entity\Articles#comentaires refers to the owning side field EventBundle\Entity\Articles#Commentaire which does not exist.**
So in the entity Articles ->

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Articles", mappedBy="Commentaire")
 */
private $comentaires;
```

ANd The entity Commentaire

```
  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Articles", inversedBy="Commentaire")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", nullable=true)
     */
private $articles;
```

Comment: What is your question? See [mcve] for how to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

It's because you write "$comentaires" instead of "$com**m**entaires" :)

And I think your annotations are false. You should write :

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Commentaire", mappedBy="Articles")
```